# Grabbing Data based another array's values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently trying to create a page which randomly generates a random set of questions and their corresponding answers. **However, I can't figure out how to match the questions to their corresponding answers.**

For the questions, I've come up with one set of arrays, and for the answers, I've come up with another:

```
//Array for Questions
var myWords = [
    'Test1',
    'Test2',
    'Test3',
    'Test4',
    'Test5',
    'Test6',
    'Test7',
    'Test8',
    'Test9',
    'Test10',
    'Test11',
    'Test12',
    'Test13',
    'Test14',
    'Test15'
]

//Array for Answers
var myAnswers = [
    'Answer1',
    'Answer2',
    'Answer3',
    'Answer4',
    'Answer5',
    'Answer6',
    'Answer7',
    'Answer8',
    'Answer9',
    'Answer10',
    'Answer11',
    'Answer12',
    'Answer13',
    'Answer14',
    'Answer15'
]
```

Based on this, I'm using the following script to pick 10 unique random questions from the first array:

```
    //randomly pick 10 words
    while(selectWords.length < 10){
        var randomWord = myWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * myWords.length)]
        if(selectWords.indexOf(randomWord) > -1) continue;
        selectWords[selectWords.length] = randomWord;
    }
```

How do I link each question with their appropriate answer in the second array? I'd like the output to show up in a table like this:

Question 1 | Answer 1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use an array of objects instead of two separate arrays?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching elements from two arrays in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552658/matching-elements-from-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a single array containing objects with both the question and answer:

```
var myQuestions = [
    { question: "Test1", answer: "Answer1" },
    { question: "Test2", answer: "Answer2" },
    ...
];
```

Then you can put these objects into your `selectWords` array, and access the `.question` and `.answer` properties when you use them.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better to define the questions with the answers at once, but if you're stuck with the input you provided, another option is to `map` them together so that when selecing a random one, you have an object containing both the question and the answer.

```js
var myWords=['Test1','Test2','Test3','Test4','Test5','Test6','Test7','Test8','Test9','Test10','Test11','Test12','Test13','Test14','Test15'];
var myAnswers=['Answer1','Answer2','Answer3','Answer4','Answer5','Answer6','Answer7','Answer8','Answer9','Answer10','Answer11','Answer12','Answer13','Answer14','Answer15'];

const questionsAndAnswers = myWords.map((question, i) => ({ question, answer: myAnswers[i] }));
const selectWords = Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => (
  questionsAndAnswers.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * questionsAndAnswers.length), 1)[0]
));
console.log(selectWords);
```

Comment: why the nested array?

Comment: Nested array? Where, what do you mean?

Comment: `[[...], [...], ...]`

Comment: Ah, you're right, thanks. Have to select the first item from `splice` array even if it's only returning one element

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I decided to combine the two arrays to make them cleaner, but this is good reference too!